# VBA Loop through range and replace value in adjacent row cell

Tags: vba, loops, offset

I have a question regarding some code which doesn't seem to be working properly for me.
I have set up some code for what I believe is a basic loop through range and replace adjacent row cell, and although no errors are occurring I am not getting the desired result.

If anyone knows better could they look through the code below and give me some advice / a fix to get things rolling:

```
For Each cCell In Range("C16,C1000")
    'perform action if cell value = "-"
    If ActiveCell.Value = "-" Then
    'move to adjacent cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    'change the cell value to "-"
    Selection.cell.Value = "-"
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End If
Next cCell
```

Comment: You are moving your selection one to the right in order to change the value and never moving your selection back, so you start in column C, and as soon as you come across "-" you move into column D. As stated in the answers below, you should avoid using select and just refer to cCell.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `ActiveCell.Value` you should just use `cCell.Value`

Also, avoid using `Select`. It's evil.

For example:

`cCell.Offset(0,1).Value = "-"`

Answer (score 0):

yes avoid using select.  But if you have to, you need to do this.  You have to select cCell in each iteration so that ActiveCell picks it up.

You don't need to use Select though and shouldn't, you can still update cCell without selecting it first. As stated by joseph4tw.

```
For Each cCell In Range("C16,C1000")
    'perform action if cell value = "-"
    cCell.select

    If ActiveCell.Value = "-" Then
      'edit adjacent cell
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "-"    
    End If
Next cCell
```